# What is the difference between get_page_link and get_permalink functions?

Tags: functions, comparison

Both functions return permalink to the post or page by it's ID. What are the differences and which of these functions should I use in which cases?

Answer (score 9):

When i explored the WordPress core for this answer i found that [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) function internally calls [get_page_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_link) function for getting permalink of page and it calls [get_post_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_permalink) function to get permalink of post.

Therefore either you use [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) function or [get_page_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_link) function, you will get same result.

The difference between these two is [get_page_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_link) function handles page_on_front page set in back end whereas [get_post_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_permalink) function do not consider it.

Comment: I just discovered that the result is not exactly the same, because get_page_link returns "page_id=XX", while get_permalink returns nice url like "page/subpage".

Comment: @RobertZelník ok. Can you tell me what's your permalink structure?

Comment: It is strange but I can not reproduce the issue anymore. Something has probably changed and now both get_page_link and get_permalink return "page_id=XX".

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion `get_page_link` is for displaying the link and `get_permalink` is not for displaying the link.

WordPress Codex says: `get_permalink`: It does NOT display the permalink.

Comment: This is a common property of all functions starting with "get_" - both get_page_link and get_permalink do not display anything, they just return a value. If we want to display the result, we can add <?php echo get_page_link($id) ?>.